# ANTLR: how to make a rewrite rule to set a lexema as a AST node text

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, antlr3, rule

The following grammar rule aims at recognizing expressions such "a-b" in a grammar that generates a AST to evaluate a linear equation:

```
tokens {
    PLUS    = '+' ;
    MINUS   = '-' ;
    DIV = '/' ;
    EQUAL = '=' ;
    MULT = '*' ;
}

minusExpr: (a=multExpr -> $a)  (MINUS b=multExpr -> ^(PLUS $a ^(MINUS $b)))*;
```

The grammar is working correctly. The only problem that I have is that in the output AST, the text of the token is set to "PLUS" instead of "+".

For example, for the equation: x-1=11

it generates the following tree (the grammar has other rules that I haven't  copy here):

(= (PLUS x (- 1)) 11)

Instead of the tree:

(= (+ x (- 1)) 11)

I would like to know how to rewrite the rule so that the AST node label is set to "+" instead of "PLUS". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The text '+' is just the input that is converted by the lexer to tokens (in that case with a token type of PLUS). You cannot rewrite that as the lexer will always convert your input to tokens (because the parser only works with tokens).

However, each token has the text it was created from internally stored. So when you walk your tree you can get the original text of each token at any time by calling getText() on the CommonToken or the BaseTree class.